# KineticJS/Canvas makes safari crash on ipad when using multiple layers?

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, kineticjs

This is driving me crazy. If I run the simple HTML below it works on my IPad2 (A1396) but not on my IPad 3 (A1416). Whenever I rotate the IPad 3 from Portrait to Landscape Safari will crash. I looks like there is a relation between the number of layers added and the width/height (of each layer).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 580,
            height: 400
        });
        var NrOfAttribute = 50;
        for (var AttributeNo = 0, NrOfAttribute; AttributeNo < NrOfAttribute; AttributeNo++) {
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 20*AttributeNo,
                y: 20*AttributeNo,
                width: 50,
                height: 10,
                fill: 'green',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 4
            });

            // add the shape to the layer
            layer.add(rect);

            // add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug or some memory problem on the IPad? Any help would be appreciated because I really need this to work.

Thanks!

Edit: I just tested to do the same with "regular" Canvas and if I increase the number of layers it will also crash (so it doesn't seem to be Kinetic specific). It will also crash on Ipad2 if you increase the number of layers enough.

Comment: I have no solution, but I can confirm it is memory related. On my iPad (A1430) Safari crashes with a low memory warning in landscape mode when starting a Kinetic page with about 50 layers of which most are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an option for you, but do you need a separate layer for each Rect, or could you put them all in the same layer? I suspect that would help reduce memory usage, as you'd wouldn't end up with 50 canvas elements. You could give each Rect a unique `name` and then still be able to manipulate them individually with something like `rect = layer.find('.{name}'); # do something with rect`